# Create potential entries for last 7 (or fewer) days in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating an internal site for filing reports. The portion in question should create links to fill out all un-filed reports in the last 7 days (in order to keep the list from getting too lengthy).

For illustrative purposes, here is an extremely simplified example of some reports in the DB:

```
id  ||  date
1   || 2013-7-1 00:00:01
2   || 2013-7-2 00:00:01
3   || 2013-7-3 00:00:01
```

Only one report can be filed per day, and a user can only ever file a report that is 7 days old or younger. So here is what needs to happen when a user enters the menu.

1. Grab report with most recent timestamp.
2. Was the report submitted for a day in the last 7 days?

   - **If yes:** Create links to potential reports for all days between (but not including) last report and today.
   - **If no:** Create links to potential reports for the last 7 days.

Using the table above, the last submitted date was July 3rd (over a week ago) - Today is July 23rd - so I would want to create links for reports for July 16th - July 22nd. I have written code that can get me this far.

**Report Class**

```
class Report {
    public $id;
    public $location;
    public $user;
    public $date;
    public $problems_encountered;
    public $problems_resolved;
    public $problems_description;

    public function __construct($location, $user, $date, $problems_encountered, $problems_resolved, $problems_description, $id=0) {
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->problems_encountered = $problems_encountered;
        $this->problems_resolved = $problems_resolved;
        $this->problems_description = $problems_description;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public static function GetMostRecent() {
        $m = getMyConnection();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `uptime_tickets` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1";
        $r = $m->query($q);
        $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
        if (is_array($row)) {
            $report = new Report(
                $row['location'],
                $row['user'],
                $row['date'],
                $row['problems_encountered'],
                $row['problems_resolved'],
                $row['problems_description'],
                $row['id']          
            );

            $m->close();
            return $report;
        }

        $m->close();
        return false;
    }

    public function was_submitted_in_last_7_days($report) {
        $start = strtotime("-1 week");
        $end = strtotime("today");

        return ((strtotime($report->date) >= $start) && (strtotime($report->date) <= $end)); 
    }
}
```

Using the 2 functions I have already defined, determining if the report was submitted in the last week is as simple as:

```
$report = Report::GetMostRecent();
if (!$report->was_submitted_in_last_7_days()) {
    // Create links for the last 7 days.
}
```

No big deal. However, I am having problems determining what to do if that report DID fall in the last 7 days. Let's assume that there was a 4th row on the previously mentioned table:

```
id  ||  date
4   || 2013-7-19 00:00:01
```

How can I programmatically create links to new reports for July 20th, 21st, and 22nd?

**For Clarification:**

The links I am referring to are simply `HTTP GET` requests - they would look something like:

`<a href="new-report.php?location=3&date=2013-7-20">Saturday, July 20th</a>`

I apologize if I went into too much detail here, but I was afraid of not covering the entire scope of what I am trying to accomplish (which is relatively simple - but hard to explain).

**Edit #1**
I gave too much background, and not enough question - here is a more relevant description:

**What I can do**
Currently, I can determine if the last report filed was for a date within the last 7 days.

**What I need to do**
If the report was filed for a date in the last 7 days (like my above example), I need to programmatically determine the days between the last filed date, and yesterday. (In the above example, I need to know how to programmatically arrive at the dates 2013-7-20, 2013-7-21, and 2013-7-22)

Comment: your question is too long, you need to ask for one thing in specific, how do i do bla bla, or something like that, and i don't mean exactly one, just be specific, instead of telling a long story.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady My question is actually quite specific, though hard to explain without the background information detailed here.

Comment: ok you said "How can I programmatically create links to new reports for July 20th, 21st, and 22nd?" what does it do now, and what do u want it to do instead ? you already showed the link format, why can't that work ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It was too long to add to a comment, so I just added Edit #1, does that answer your question?

Comment: you mean the difference in days ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Kindof - but I actually need the dates returned to me as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if I got this right or not, but I'm going to try,
First we need a new method to get the reports from the last 7 days,

```
public function getLastWeekReports($user_id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `uptime_tickets` WHERE `user` = '$user_id' AND
    `date` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ORDER BY `date` DESC";
     # rest of processing to return report array
}
```

Then get the missing reports dates

```
public function getMissingDates($reports)
{
    $missing_dates = array();
    foreach(range(-1, -7) as $diff) {
        $missing_dates[] = new DateTime($diff." days");
    }
    foreach($reports as $report) {
        $key = array_search($report->date, $missing_dates);
        if($key!==false){
            unset($missing_dates[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $missing_dates;
}
```

That would return the dates that have no reports, we need to turn them into links

```
public function createLink($date)
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $url = "<a href='new-report.php?location=3&date=".
           date("Y-j-d", $timestamp).
           "'>".
           date("l, F jS",$timestamp).
           "</a>";

    return $url;
}
```

You can easily do a `foreach` with the dates array and call the `createLink()`

I hope I was close to what you needed.

Comment: Haven't tested this yet, but I think you nailed it. This is much simpler than what I was trying to do. I'll let you know how this works and mark you as accepted.

Comment: It took a little bit of modification (which was to be expected), but this works fantastic. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

for all 7 days leave array blank
to skip date(s) just populate with dates to skip in the format of 2013-7-20

```
function create_links_for_last_7_days($skips=array()) {
    $i = -7;
    while ($i < 0) {
        $i++;
          $date = date_create("$i days");
          $date_numeric = $date->format("Y-m-d");
          if (!in_array($date_numeric,$skips)){
              echo "<a href='new-report.php?location=3&amp;date=$date_numeric'>".$date->format("l jS F Y")."</a><br/>";
              }
          }
       }
```

Of course simpler would just be to populate the skips array with datetime objects and not bother with $date_numeric.

Also you'll probably need to determine all days that have been submitted in the last 7 rather than just the most recent but that should be pretty easy too.

(code tested as working in isolation: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/iex-wjp)
HTH;
Nick

Comment: just saw your comment and to get an array instead of course instead of using echo just fill an array an return it.

Comment: just read your edit#1: in which case change my code to be `$skips="2013-07-19"` (or similar) and change the one if statement to be `if ($date_numeric > $skips) {`